# Need help using promise and future for the first time in C++ 14

Tags: multithreading, lambda, promise, c++14, future

i'm currently coding a chess game which includes a chess IA to play with. My chess IA working fine with minimax and alpha beta optimisation. But now, I would like to make it faster by using multithreading. It's my first time of using thread so I started first by running the minimax function on a single separate thread to test it out.

This is my code :
`

```
std::function<std::pair<Move*, float>(Board, int, float, float, bool , bool)> task;

task = [&task](Board &board, int depth, float alpha, float beta, bool maximizingPlayer, bool maximizingColor) ->std::pair<Move*, float>

{ 
    if (depth == 0 || board.GameIsOver())
         return std::make_pair(nullptr, evaluate(board, maximizingColor));

     auto possibleMoves = board.AllMovePossible(maximizingPlayer);
     Move bestMove;
     if (maximizingPlayer) {
         float maxEval = INFINITY;
         for (PossibleMoves& p : possibleMoves) {
             for (auto& move : p.moves) {
                 board.Move(p.piece, move.first, move.second);
                 int currentEval = task(board, depth - 1, alpha, beta, false, maximizingColor).second;
                 board.UndoMove();
                 if (currentEval < maxEval) {
                     maxEval = currentEval;
                     bestMove = Move(p.piece, move);
                 }
                 beta = min(beta, currentEval);
                 if (beta <= alpha)
                     break;
             }
         }
         return std::make_pair(&bestMove, maxEval);
     }
     else {
         float maxEval = -INFINITY;
         for (PossibleMoves& p : possibleMoves) {
             for (auto& move : p.moves) {
                 board.Move(p.piece, move.first, move.second);
                 int currentEval = task(board, depth - 1, alpha, beta, true, maximizingColor).second;
                 board.UndoMove();
                 if (currentEval > maxEval) {
                     maxEval = currentEval;
                     bestMove = Move(p.piece, move);
                 }
                 alpha = max(alpha, currentEval);
                 if (beta <= alpha)
                     break;
             }
         }
         return std::make_pair(&bestMove, maxEval);
    }};

std::function<void(std::promise<std::pair<Move*, float>>, Board, int, float, float, bool, bool)> taskWorker;

taskWorker = [&task](std::promise<std::pair<Move*, float>> &&p, Board board, int depth, float alpha, float beta, bool maximizingPlayer, bool maximizingColor)
{std::pair<Move*, int> bestMove = task(board, depth, alpha, beta, maximizingPlayer, maximizingColor);
    p.set_value(bestMove);
};

std::promise<std::pair<Move*, float>> p;
auto f = p.get_future();

std::thread worker(taskWorker,std::move(p),board,depth, alpha, beta, maximizingPlayer, maximizingColor);

std::pair<Move*, int> bestMoveFromThread = f.get();

worker.join();

return bestMoveFromThread;`
```

To explain my code: the lambda function task is my minimax function, it is using recursion and returning the best move for a board past by reference.

Then the taskWorker is what the thread is going to do. It takes a promise in parameter to store the future best move and use the task function to find it. It also takes a copy of the board because i would like to have multiple thread later that doesn't play moves on the same board.

Then I set up my promise p and my future f and I launch the thread with the function taskWorker
then wait for it to end to get the result store in future. But my problem is that f.get() doesn't have result.

Although the thread seems to work fine because when i debug it seems to find the best move and p.set-value(bestMove) change p to 'has-result' with the correct best move stored (screenshots of debugging linked).

So the problem seems to be between std::promise<std::pair<Move*, float>> p; and std::pair<Move*, int> bestMoveFromThread = f.get();

It's my first time using promise and future, so I simply copied examples I found on the internet.

Did I misunderstand something about promise and future ?
Am I not using these correctly ?

Thanks for your answers. (sorry if that came out wrong, I am not native english speaker).

[(debugging) promise in the thread](https://i.stack.imgur.com/die1S.png)

[(debugging) promise out of the thread](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GRE12.png)

Comment: Well, if I may be a bit critical, when you start a thread and then immediately `join` with the thread, you're not multithreading at all.  You still have a single thread of execution.  Right?  The only way to gain is to have many things being computed at once.  With this kind of task, that's not easy, because the next moves all depend on THIS move.

Comment: Like I said, for now, I'm testing thread for the first time so i starded with one thread. But i understand what you say and my idea in the future is to split the list of possible move into the number of threads that my computer is offering then each threads are going to resolve the best move from possible moves that it  got then i simply find the best one between those threads by comparing the evaluation linked to the move. I know that my alpha beta optimization is going to be a bit fucked up, I will think about this later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're returning a pointer to a local variable (Move* from the task). So there's already big potential for unexpected issues. Also, in some places your pair contains an int, in others a float. That type confusing might explain the rest.

Generally you understand future/promise I think. But for this example you should look into std::async to replace the thread object.

Comment: Indeed, the issue came from that, thank you very much !